# Detener ejecución de una función en Javascript antes de comenzar otra

Tags: javascript, firebase

Existen dos botones en mi programa, uno que genera una sumatoria y otra que genera una resta, entonces, cada vez que presiono btnsiguiente, empieza a sumar (+1) y, cada vez que presiono btnanterior, comienza a restar (-1). Cuando ejecuto la sumatoria no tengo ningún problema, pero al realizar la resta se me genera un error que no se detiene y me crashea la página, debido a que estoy trabajando con una db de Firebase y cada vez que sumo +1 cambio al usuario que contiene el número de la sumatoria, y cuando resto me devuelvo al usuario anterior de la sumatoria, pero al realizar la resta se genera el problema y empieza a generar cambios sin parar entre el número siguiente y el anterior...

Estas son las dos funciones que tengo

```
function btnsiguiente() {
  var numero = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    numero = isNaN(numero) ? 0 : numero;
    numero++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = numero;
    document.getElementById('numero').innerHTML = numero;

var postElement1 = document.getElementById("postElement1");

var updateStarCount1 = function(element1, value) {
    element1.textContent = value;
};

var starCountRef1 = firebase.database().ref().child(userpais).child(userciudad).child(usertipodeempresa)
                    .child(userusuario + "_" + userdireccion).child(selectedtap).child(numero+'').child("Atendido"); 

starCountRef1.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    updateStarCount1(postElement1, snapshot.val()); 

    var numeroanterior = numero - 1;

    if (snapshot.val() === "No") {

      var firebaseRef1 = firebase.database().ref().child(userpais).child(userciudad).child(usertipodeempresa)
                    .child(userusuario + "_" + userdireccion).child(selectedtap).child(numero+'').child("Atendido");
      firebaseRef1.set("Sí");

if (numero >= 2) {
    var firebaseRef11 = firebase.database().ref().child(userpais).child(userciudad).child(usertipodeempresa)
                    .child(userusuario + "_" + userdireccion).child(selectedtap).child(numeroanterior+'').child("Atendido");
      firebaseRef11.set("Sí");

}

  } //termino if()

});

} //fin btn function

function btnanterior() {
  var numero = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    numero = isNaN(numero) ? 0 : numero;
    numero--;
    document.getElementById('number').value = numero;
    document.getElementById('numero').innerHTML = numero;


// some HTML element on the page
var postElement1 = document.getElementById("postElement1");

var updateStarCount1 = function(element1, value) {
    element1.textContent = value;
};

var starCountRef1 = firebase.database().ref().child(userpais).child(userciudad).child(usertipodeempresa)
                    .child(userusuario + "_" + userdireccion).child(selectedtap).child(numero+'').child("Atendido"); 

starCountRef1.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    updateStarCount1(postElement1, snapshot.val()); 

    var numerosiguiente = numero + 1;

    if (snapshot.val() === "Sí") {

      var firebaseRef1 = firebase.database().ref().child(userpais).child(userciudad).child(usertipodeempresa)
                    .child(userusuario + "_" + userdireccion).child(selectedtap).child(numero+'').child("Atendido");
      firebaseRef1.set("No");

if (numero >= 1) {
    var firebaseRef11 = firebase.database().ref().child(userpais).child(userciudad).child(usertipodeempresa)
                    .child(userusuario + "_" + userdireccion).child(selectedtap).child(numerosiguiente+'').child("Atendido");
      firebaseRef11.set("No");
}

  } //termino if()

} //fin btn function
```

No sé cómo podría hacer para que cada vez que ejecute una de las dos funciones, esta se detenga antes de presionar nuevamente el botón para que no siga trabajando con la función anterior y no la tome en cuenta...

Muchas gracias!

Comment: dejame ver si entiendo cuando haga click en un boton quieres que sume y cuando le de click en otro quieres que reste?, puedo darte un ejemplo con javascript nativo?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que eso si me funciona y cada vez que presiono siguiente, suma 1 y cuando presiono el botón anterior resta 1 a la sumatoria, pero el error ocurre con la db de Firebase, que al estar cambiando de usuarios, por ejemplo: usuario 1, 2, 3 , 4 , 5 y luego presiono el botón anterior, debería volver al usuario 4, entonces vuelve, pero al haber estado en el usuario 5 se genera un error en el que empieza a generar datos en el usuario 4 y 5 sin parar y se crashea la página.

Comment: entonnces debes crear un valor unico de usuario con el contador y asi solucionaras tu problema

Comment: Cómo sería eso @JackNavaRow

Comment: algo como `number[tu_user] = value`